# Pointers Homework

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, type-conversion

If anyone can help me finish this and point out what had to be done to make the program work, that would be great.

-ask for how many days user wants to enter from 1-365 (validate)

-ask for temperature for each days between -60 and 90 degrees Celsius (loop, validate)

-convert each value to Fahrenheit (function)

-output results (function)

Problem

-the users should input a int Celsius number, a whole number but it converts to a double fahrenheit number
ex. 4 celsius converts to 39.20 fahrenheit

- for this code...

  cout << "Celsius temperature for Day " << i+1 << " : ";

  *(days + 1) = GetValidInt("", TEMP_MIN, TEMP_MAX);

it outputs and waits for the input on a new line...how can i make it wait for input on the same line?

```
    #include <IOSTREAM> // input/outout stream
    #include <IOMANIP>  // for setw manipulator
    #include <CFLOAT>   // for limits of a double DBL_MIN and DBL_MAX
    #include <CLIMITS>  // for limits of a int INT_MIN and INT_MAX

    using namespace std;

    //Function Prototypes
    double GetValidDouble(string prompt = "", const double MIN = DBL_MIN, const double MAX = DBL_MAX);
    int GetValidInt(string prompt = "", const int MIN = INT_MIN, const int MAX = INT_MAX);
    int outputFunc (int*);
    double calcCelsius(double*);
    int main() {
            //Constants
            const int TEMP_MIN = -90;
            const int TEMP_MAX = 60;
            const int DAYS_MIN = 1;
            const int DAYS_MAX = 365;
            //Pointer
            int numDays;
            int *days;
            //Determine the number of days to get input for
            //Validation - Must be numeric || Between 1 - 365
            numDays = GetValidInt("How many days do you wish to enter? ", DAYS_MIN, DAYS_MAX);

            //Array Allocation
            cout << "TEMPRETURE REPORTER" << endl;
            cout << "====================" << endl;
            cout << "Please enter the tempreture for each day." << endl;
            try{
                    days = new int[numDays];
                        for(int i = 0; i < numDays; i++){
                            cout << "Celsius temperature for Day " << i+1 << " : ";
                            *(days + 1) = GetValidInt("", TEMP_MIN, TEMP_MAX);
                            //Validation - Between -90.00C and 60.00C
                        }
                        //for loop
                        for(int i = 0; i < numDays; i++){
                                cout << "" << outputFunc(&days);
                              }
                        //output function
                    delete[] days;
                }
            catch(bad_alloc){
                    cout << "\nCould not allocate that amount memory.";
                }
            cout << endl << endl;
            system("pause");
            return 0;
            }
            //An inline function is a function upon which the compiler has been requested to perform inline expansion. 
            //In other words, the programmer has requested that the compiler insert the complete body of the function 
            //in every place that the function is called, rather than generating code to call the function in the one place it is defined.
            inline double calcCelsius(double* celsius){
                double fahrenheit = 0;
                fahrenheit = (celsius*9/5)+32;
                return fahrenheit;
            }
            //Output Function
            int outputFunc (int* days){
                double fahrenheit = 0;
                //PROCESS
                //double     //&days int
                fahrenheit = calcCelsius(&days); //Calling calcCelsius
                //OUTPUT
                cout << right << setw(15) << "Day " << numDays << setw(10) << fahrenheit << char(248) << "F" << setw(10) << numDays << char(248) << "C" << endl;
            }
            double GetValidDouble(string prompt, const double MIN, const double MAX){
               double validNumber = 0.0; // holds the user input
               string rubbish;           // holds garbage input.

               cout << endl << prompt << " "; 
               cin >> validNumber;       // try to get input
               if(cin.fail()){           // if user input fails...
                   cin.clear();              // reset the cin object
                   cin >> rubbish;           // cleans garbage from cin.

                   // report the problem to the user.
                   cerr << "\nInvalid input. Please try again and enter a numeric value.\n";
                   // Try again by calling the function again (recursion)
                   validNumber = GetValidDouble(prompt, MIN, MAX);
               } 
               else if(validNumber < MIN || validNumber > MAX){// if value is outside range...
                   // report the problem to the user.
                   cerr << "\nInvalid input. Please try again and enter a value between "
                        << MIN << " and " << MAX << ".\n";
                   // Try again by call the function again (recursion)
                   validNumber = GetValidDouble(prompt, MIN, MAX);
               }
               return validNumber; // returns a valid value to the calling function.
            }
            int GetValidInt(string prompt, const int MIN, const int MAX){
                   double validNumber = 0.0; // holds the user input
                   validNumber = GetValidDouble(prompt, MIN, MAX); // get a number
                   if((int) validNumber < validNumber) // if the value is not a whole number...
                   {
                       cerr << "\nInvalid input. Please try again and enter a whole number.\n";
                       // Try again by calling the function again (recursion)
                       validNumber = GetValidInt(prompt, MIN, MAX);
                   }
                   return (int) validNumber; // returns a valid value to the calling function.
            }
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? The question is clear, and the OP has given it a thorough go first, afaict.

Comment: In function `double calcCelsius(double*)': 
59 invalid operands of types `double*' and `int' to binary `operator*' 
59 At global scope:
62 'Output' does not name a type

Comment: my problem lies in both the calcCelsius function & the outputFunc functions...i want the outputFunc to take in the *days pointer and convert all the values stored in them. but! as i stated before the users should input a int celsius number, a whole number but it converts to a double fahrenheit.

Comment: You realize you've misspelled "temperature" at least twice in your output, once in all-caps, right?

Comment: no i didnt realize, i just did it on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You are outputting a line break before requesting the number:

```
  cout << endl << prompt << " ";  // Output a line break ????
  cin >> validNumber;       // try to get i
```

Just remove the first line above.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

```
cout << endl << prompt << " ";
```

in `getValidDouble`. It outputs a newline character before getting the value from the user, *after* you've output your own prompt.

Why are you not actually *using* the `prompt` parameter to ask for something? It's obviously there for a reason :-)

That way, it would be output after the newline and your input would be on the same line. In other words, something like changing:

```
cout << "Celsius temperature for Day " << i+1 << " : ";
*(days + 1) = GetValidInt("", TEMP_MIN, TEMP_MAX);
```

into:

```
#include <sstream>
:
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "Celsius temperature for Day " << (i+1) << " : ";
*(days + 1) = GetValidInt (ss.str(), TEMP_MIN, TEMP_MAX);
```

That should fix your immediate problem, the newline after the prompt. You also have some *other* problems, such as passing wrong data types to functions but I'll leave them for you to fix since it'll make you a better programmer. One hint, compile with warnings on, and *read* what the compiler tells you.

Comment: thank you, i was trying to do that but didnt know exactly how.

Comment: nvm, that didn`t seem to work...gives error "invalid operands of type"

Comment: @user1087935, I changed the code to get rid of that error. You have _other_ errors over and above what you asked about but I don't want to do too much of the work for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

TRY and I do mean try, xcode doesn't flag any errors but don't have the time to run it and debug it, this (obviously its not complete, just cut&paste it on top of yours)

```
    //Function Prototypes
double GetValidDouble(string prompt = "", const double MIN = DBL_MIN, const double MAX = DBL_MAX);
int GetValidInt(string prompt = "", const int MIN = INT_MIN, const int MAX = INT_MAX);
void outputFunc (int*,int);
double calcCelsius(double*);
int main() {
    //Constants
    const int TEMP_MIN = -90;
    const int TEMP_MAX = 60;
    const int DAYS_MIN = 1;
    const int DAYS_MAX = 365;
    //Pointer
    int numDays;
    int *days;
    //Determine the number of days to get input for
    numDays = GetValidInt("How many days do you wish to enter? ", DAYS_MIN, DAYS_MAX);  //Validation - Must be numeric || Between 1 - 365

    //Array Allocation
    cout << "TEMPRETURE REPORTER" << endl;
    cout << "====================" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the tempreture for each day." << endl;
    try{
        days = new int[numDays];
        for(int i = 0; i < numDays; i++){
            string prompt = "Celsius temperature for Day "  + (i+1);
            *(days + 1) = GetValidInt(prompt, TEMP_MIN, TEMP_MAX); //Validation - Between TEMP_MIN and TEMP_MAX
        }
        //for loop
        for(int i = 1; i < numDays; i++){
            cout << "" ;
            outputFunc(days,i);  //we send the whole array
        }
        //output function
        delete[] days;
    }
    catch(bad_alloc){
        cout << "\nCould not allocate that amount memory.";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
//An inline function is a function upon which the compiler has been requested to perform inline expansion. 
//In other words, the programmer has requested that the compiler insert the complete body of the function 
//in every place that the function is called, rather than generating code to call the function in the one place it is defined.
inline double calcCelsius(int celsius){
    return (celsius*9/5)+32; //parentheses not really needed
}
//Output Function
void outputFunc (int* days, int a){
    int temp = days[a];
    cout << right << setw(15) << "Day " << a << setw(10) << calcCelsius(temp) << char(248) << "F" << setw(10) << &days << char(248) << "C" << endl;
}
```

I didnt change anything else. I dont know if this is really what you need, i mean it gets the job done (probably) or at least it will with a few changes. But I dont know if you are supposed to be using anything in particular.

Main changes:

- The outputFunc is now void and couts in it. You can either do this or
  have it return a std::string and output that. But you cant have it
  return an int, and output inside it (well you CAN, but its not what
  you need here).
- newDay is out of context in outputFunc, so you need
  to pass it. But anyway its the counter you need to send.
- calcCelcius (which i'd named deg2far or celc2far) now returns a
  double and takes an int (still inline)
- Remember that you are storing values in i+1 (starting with 0)
  therefore your first value is in days[1] ... output loop should start
  at 1.

There might be some other changes (obviously the prototype for the funcs) but those are the major.

i'm not really sure if line 54 `string prompt = "Celsius temperature for Day "  + (i+1);` will work, maybe you need to declare it separately.